# acquire of google api key for OAuth 2.0 In Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth

After getting an access-token, I don't know how to use google API.
I tried to add 'access_token' but the error message displays 403: the request cannot be identified with a client project. Please pass a valid API Key with the request.

so I mixed up because I didn't get any API Key from OAuth.  Please, does anyone knows how to get valid API key?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Using OAuth 2.0 for Client-side Web Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent)?

The process is described quite nicely there. If you successfully received and verified the `access_token`, you can scroll down to [Calling a Google API](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#callinganapi) to see how to make `API` calls using the `access_token`.

If you need help with using a specific `Google API`, visit that `API`'s documentation page. (e.g. [Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/), [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/) etc.)

Make sure you have needed **`API`s enabled** and relevant **credentials set up** correctly from the [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/)

Comment: Yes I read it. and I did it the way it described. for instance, https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{{spreadsheet ID}}/values/{{the name of the spreadsheet}}!A1:D3?access_token={{WHATEVER_CLIENT-ID}}. and What I was asked was 403: the request cannot be identified with a client project. Please pass a valid API Key with the request.

Comment: Do you have a valid API Key for Sheets API? https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/js#step_1_turn_on_the_api_name

Comment: I read 'the Acquiring and using an API key' on google sheet v4, tried to follow. I already created a credentials for OAuth 2.0 client IDs. that's how I got my access_token

Comment: And I enabled Sheets API on my google account. That's all I need. I don't know what other step I didn't follow

Comment: Ozan, Are you saying I have to create one OAuth  credentials and one API Key credential to request google sheet API??

Comment: *"403: the request cannot be identified with a client project"* strongly suggests that the problem is with your app credentials. You either set up wrong credentials or you are passing the wrong key. Do you see a yellow warning window informing you to setup credentials when you go to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/sheets.googleapis.com/overview ?

Comment: When I see the Traffic, there is 400, 403 status.  I might set up the wrong key. or I don't even know how to set up api key with OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the api key along with the url; to do that just add the parameter "key=API_KEY", for example:
sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets{{spreadsheet ID}}/values/{{the name of the spreadsheet}}!A1:D3?key={{API_KEY}}